# Citation in parenthesis with additional information

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am trying to add additional information (e.g. theorem-numbers or sections) in my citations, e.g.[image]

How do I do this?

Comment: Please tell us which bibliography style you employ. And, do you currently employ a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`?

Comment: If you want to add additional information use `\cite{...}` with its optional argument, e.g. `\cite[Section~8.3]{ki2016}`.  What is the problem in your case?  (Please check if your used citation package changes this behavior.)

Comment: @BerndRaichle this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read a LaTeX manual:

If you want to add additional information use `\cite{...}` with its optional argument, e.g. `\cite[Section~8.3]{ki2016}`.

Citation package like `biblatex`, `natbib`, `cite` etc. allows you to change the formatting.  Please refer to the documentation of these packages if you need more formatting changes.